# Is there package for Sublime Text 2 that displays git branch in side bar after root folder's name?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Googled this topic unsuccessfully. May be you guys can help me out.

**Title is the question:**
?? Is there package for Sublime Text 2 that displays git branch in side bar after root folder's name ??

Just as convenience rather then anything else.

Comment: like aptana studio does as of latest. I am new to Sublime Text editor, but i like it alot so far.

Comment: this is a 2 years old question, but still quite relevant. has anyone created such a package?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, i have kind of got used to this. I mostly use command line and source tree in conjunction so this became some what irrelevant to me i think. May be there is now such package, should probably search again.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just discovered this myself. As noted in [ST forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=2119#p26290) the [SideBarGit](https://github.com/SublimeText/SideBarGit) plugin places current branch in the statusbar:

[image: Git branch in ST2 statusbar]

Comment: thank you @lass, i had this plugin for a while. i was really wondering if anything displays branch by the root folder.

Comment: will accept your answer though, don't think any one be adding anything new soon : )

Comment: For people using Sublime Text 3, there is a st3 branch you can pull using git. On windows, you can go on `C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`, `git clone https://github.com/SublimeText/SideBarGit.git` and then `git checkout st3` to proceed to the sublime text 3 branch. Now it should work for you.

Comment: after installing from GUI seems not working on Mac OS X 10.10 :(